# How do I add someone's website link in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to add some ticket booking links in my app. How do I add? I used webview that open the links in a browser. But is it correct?

Comment: Sounds kind of correct, but without your code and a description of your problem, I can't really tell you...

Comment: You can attach a textview this website and you can use a fragment to open it in a webview.

Comment: Webview.getSetting(). setJavaScriptEnabled(true) ;   Webview.loadUrl(".... ") ;

Comment: My XML  :: <RelativeLayout....  <Webview android:layout_height="match_parent " android:layout_width="match_parent " > </RelativeLayout>

Comment: What question can i ask??  Why some people always give negative mark without mentioning a reason

Comment: If you are trying to integrate a website in your app which does not belong to you then google may ban your app . Get permission from  the website owner to display it in the app or open it in an intent for a browser app or use custom tabs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **TextView** to add link in your app.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/link_to_google"
    />
```

To make your string as link, add your string in String.xml..for example

```
  <string name="link_to_google"><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to 
   Google</a></string>
```

and at last, call setMovementMethod on your textView

```
TextView textView =findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: @keerthi if the answer was helpful..please upvote the answer :)